# How to solve xaxis update issue in highchart while switching tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm using highcharts in my react app. I have 2 tabs on my page namely hour and day. When I click the day tab, it displays an area chart based on the dates given in categories. When I click the hour tab it displays an area chart based on the time using DateTime x-axis type.

It works fine when I'm using any one of the tabs. But the problem is when I visited the hour tab and switched to the day tab all the x-axis labels are displayed as milliseconds instead of dates. This problem happened if I visited the day tab first and followed by the hour tab, all the x-axis labels are displayed as milliseconds.

```
fun(){ 
        if(this.state.current !="hour"){           
                this.xaxis = {'categories':[],'type':'line'}
                this.xaxis.categories = ['26-10-2019','27-10-2019','28-10-2019']
                var obj2={}
                this.series=[]
                obj2['data']=[6,37,29]
                obj2['name'] = "data from november"
                obj2['type']='area'
                this.series.push(obj2)
                this.setState({options:{series:this.series,xAxis :this.xaxis}})           
        }
        else{          
                    var result = [[1574787600000, 3],[1574798400000, 23],[1574863200000, 1]]                   
                    this.series=[]
                    var obj={}
                    obj['data']=result
                    obj['pointInterval'] = 24*3600*1000
                    this.xaxis ={}
                    this.xaxis['type']='datetime'
                    this.xaxis['tickInterval']=24*3600*1000
                    this.series.push(obj)
                    this.setState({options:{series:this.series,xAxis : this.xaxis}},()=>{})     
        }
}
```

The above function is called whenever switching the tabs.Options state variable is passed to parameter for  highchart componenent.

Output image :

[image]

What was the mistake I did?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behaviour on some online editor which will allow me to see your config? You don't need to reproduce the whole project, just this issue. You can use this template: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-7d1nd

Comment: @SebastianWędzel link : https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-flower-c8kp9?from-embed  its working fine here.But not displayed properly in my local .What was the problem ?

Comment: To be honest - I don't know what do you want to achieve. The codes which you have sent in the codesandbox and above code from the topic are different. In the above code you are using once categories, once not. In the reproduced demo not at all. It is not recommended to switch between datatim' and categories type. I recommend you, to avoid this type of errors, to keep one type of data and xAxis options.

Comment: I apologize  @SebastianWędzel , I have uploaded the wrong file in code sandbox.That's my mistake. Can you check and tell me what was the mistake?

Comment: Here is a demo with a corrected code from your question. Please compare it to yours. Remember that you need to change every option  - for example if you set tickInterval in one condition, remember to bring it back on the next one, same about categories. https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-fire-k3odb

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thank you for the timely help.It worked.